# What would go wrong if quantum observables were not represented by linear operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, observables, non-linear-systems

If quantum mechanical operators corresponding to physical observables were not hermitian, the corresponding eigenvalues may not be real. Since the eigenvalues are the outcomes of measurements of physical observables, they better be real. This justifies what would go wrong if the operators were non-hermitian. What would go wrong if the operators corresponding to physical observables were nonlinear or antilinear?

Comment: Not all physical observables must be in a real domain. For example take a look into complex refractive index : $$ {\underline {n}}=n-i\kappa . $$ where $\kappa$ stands for light looses (or gain) in a medium.

Comment: How do you define *eigenvalues* for *non-linear* operators?

Comment: Suggestion: For a more focused question, consider to only ask about non-linearity, and leave non-hermiticity & non-reality out of it.